# Changing class functionality

Tags: c++, class

I am learning classes and I have a task just to practice for myself, and I need to modify this class:

```
class Object {
    // modify this
};

template <typename Object>
void test(){
    Object z, y(2);
    if (z.x() == y.y()){
        const Object x;
        if (x.y() == Object::z())
            return;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    test<Object>();
    return 0;
}
```

Nothing can be changed, only that class, so the code compiles without no errors. I am new to classes and it is hard for me to understand what exactly I have to put into that class so it compiles. I thought I need to make two constructors one with no no parameters and another with one parameter, then those `x()` and `y()` functions, but I am still getting errors. Well I mean I just did this:

```
class Object {
public:
    Object() {
        x1 = 2;
        y1 = 2;
    }
    Object(int a) {
        x1 = a;
        y1 = a;
    }
    int x() {
        return x1;
    }
    int y() {
        return y1;
    }
private:
    int x1;
    int y1;
};

template <typename Object>
void test() {
    Object z, y(2);
    if (z.x() == y.y()) {
        const Object x;
        if (x.y() == Object::z())
            return;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    test<Object>();
    return 0;
}
```

I would be thankful if you would help me out on how this should look like..

Comment: int x() const; will fix one of your problem, the other one is caused by the missing of a static function called z

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi: Actually, `int y() const;`. naming is confusing.

Comment: well I meant to suggest both of them to be const :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Turned out somewhat messy (?). Still open to constructive criticism:

```
class Object {
    int foo;
public:
    // Both the default constructor and the one that takes an int
    Object(const int &i = 1) : foo(i) {} 
    // Member functions
    static int z() { return 1; }
    int x() { return 1; }
    int y() const { return 1; }
};
```

As for the second one, try this:

```
class Object { 
    int foo;
public: 
    struct X { // Nested class
        int y() { return 2; } // for y.x.y()
    };
    X x; // for the same

    // Both the default constructor and the one that takes an int
    Object(const int &i = 1) : foo(i) {}

    bool operator<(const Object &o) { return 1; } // for std::sort
    int operator()() { return 0; } // for x[0]()
    Object operator++(int) { return *this; } // for x[1]++
    int y() { return 2; } // for x[1]++y.() 
};
```

Note the use of the nested class. As with the first task, since it is not prohibited, it is permitted. Maybe there's another way to deal with the `y.x.y()` but didn't come up with anything more elegant *(will be glad to accept any input and suggestions!)*.

Comment: Oh it was this simple just to use ```return 1```, thank you!

Comment: @Norbertas since no requirements for this, why not to simplify ;)

Comment: I would use 2 constructors instead of 1 with a default const int ref for a beginner. The default and the one taking an int.

Comment: @ServeLaurijssen makes sense! Just decided to keep it compact.

Comment: @rawrex Sorry I can't ask another question because of the timer in stackoverflow, but I have a question with this one - #include <algorithm>

class Object {
 // Modify this again
};

template <typename Object>

void test() {
 Object x[5], y = x[0]() + x[1]++.y();
 std::sort(x, x + 5);
 if (y.x.y() == 2) {
  return;
 }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
 test<Object>();
 return 0;
}
    As I understand everything is the same but I have to overload operators now?

Comment: @Norbertas will take a look shortly!

Comment: @Norbertas you may edit in the second question while we are at it. I will edit in answer (if any) shortly.

Comment: @rawrex I can just edit this question and put the other code in here maybe

Comment: @Norbertas seems to be done, check the edit.